# Way to call hooks from button events in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time to develop a react application. I intend to make an Api call when user clicked a button. Is it possible to directly call a hook from an event? If yes, how can I call it if the hook was from a different component?

This is the button (different component)

```
 const paginationButtons = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button onClick={() => viewDetails()}>View Details</Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

function viewDetails() {
   //Is it Possible to call fetch data.js and pass the url from here?
  }
```

This is the hook for fetch data.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const propTypes = {
  initialUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  initialParams: PropTypes.object
}

export const useFetchData = props => {
  PropTypes.checkPropTypes(propTypes, props, 'property', 'useFetchData');

  const { initialUrl, initialParams } = props;

  const [request, setRequest] = useState({
    url: initialUrl,
    params: initialParams
  });
  const [loading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const {url, params} = request;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const result = await axios(url, {params: {...params}});
        setIsLoading(false);
        setData(result.data);
      } catch(err) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(err);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [request]);

  const doFetch = (params) => {
    setRequest({url: request.url, params: params});
  };
  return {loading, error, data, doFetch};
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can do that if `viewDetails` is inside a component.import hook,move `viewDetails` inside component.

Answer (score 15):

What you intend to do is possible, but in my opinion, it shouldn't be done in a real-world application. Here's why.

First, let's consider why we would want to use a hook. React function components had no way of preserving **local state** and **handling lifecycle events** between rerenders. This is why hooks were introduced.

Before I use a hook, I would ask myself, "Do I need to handle component state or the component life-cycle?". If not, using a hook is either overkill or an anti-pattern.

In your example, let's consider what you may be trying to do with the `viewDetails` function. Obviously, you want to do the fetch call, but what do you intend to do afterward? Let's see some possibilities...

1. Update the dom imperatively: You shouldn't do imperative operations unless there is a very specific reason. Let's assume, you want to show an alert, then, of course, you can call an imperative API (like notie.js or sweet-alert for instance).
2. Update the dom reactively: This is the most common scenario I think. In such a case, you should either call some `setState` function, or fire an event to be captured by another component. In either case, there's no use of using a hook for fetching data.

Thus instead of trying to call a hook like `useFetchData`, you should call a function like `doFetchData`.

I am not suggesting that you should get rid of the `useFetchData` hook. It's just, they serve different purposes. It makes sense to use the hook for any fetch operations that should happen at load time rather than as a response to a user action.

---

Now that I have given my opinion, here's one way you can trigger a hook based on user action.

```
// Here we are using a shouldFetch flag to conditionally call a function
function useFetch(url, options, shouldFetch, setShouldFetch) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        if (shouldFetch) {
            doFetch(url, options)
                // set the fetch result to local state
                .then(data => {
                   setState(data)
                   setShouldFetch(false) // avoid infinite calls
                }) 
        }
    });

    return [state]; // You can maybe add fetch status as well
}
```

Now you can use it like this,

```
function MyComponent() {
    const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(false);
    const [fetchData] = useFetch('url', {}, shouldFetch, setShouldFetch);

    return (
        <Button onClick={() => {setShouldFetch(true)}}>Click Me</Button>
    )
}
```

But really, you shouldn't use a hook this way. A regular `doFetchData` call is the way to go. Call some setState functions to preserve the fetched data if you need to.

Comment: Hi Pubudu, Thank you for your response.The purpose of the button is to pass the url link to the hook (eg. urlhere/viewDetail/100001) which the id is appended to the url, and then retrieve the response by a different component for rendering.

Comment: `function viewDetails() {
  // const url= "urlhere/viewDetail/" + detail;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

you may need context

```
const Context = React.createContext(null);

function FetchProvider(props){
   const state = useFetchData(props);
   return (
     <Context.Provider value={state}>{props.children}</Context.Provider>
   )
}

function Button(){
   const { doFetch } = React.useContext(Context);
   const handleClick = React.useCallback(()=> doFetch({id: ""}), [])
   return <button onClick={handleClick}>Fetch</button>
}

function ViewDetails(){
   const {data, error, loading} = React.useContext(Context);
   if (loading) { return <div>Loading</div> }
   if (error) { return <div>{error.message}</div> }
   return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
}

function Page(){
   return (
     <FetchProvider initialUrl="/url" initialParams={{id: ""}}>
       <ViewDetails/>
       <Button/>
     </FetchProvider >
   );
}
```